# disable generic validation in pom.xml or maven without eclipse

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Actually, in interface we are using the generic but not in implementation class properly.This code is compiling and running on tomcat properly.

Now, i am writing pom.xml for maven 3.5 for this web project without eclipse.
But while i am executing the "mvn package" command or "mvn clean intall" for war creation on console, on pom.xml, it shows compile time error :
**name clash: create(com.test1.storage.entities.SalesOrderArchive) in com.test1.storage.dao.impl.SalesOrderArchiveDaoImpl overrides a method whose erasure is the same as another method, yet neither overrides the other**

Is there any way to disable this validation in pom.xml. Any solution without change in java code ????

Comment: Ahm...sorry but your code has a problem..which means the compiler can't handle that ...so you have to change your code....Apart from that I have my doubts that your code is running on tomcat properly...if you can't compile the code...If such option would exist it would be part of the java compiler...

Comment: Eclipse is showing only warning  not error in code.So, this code is running properly on tomcat for last 1 year.I want the way to disable/ avoid the generic validation in pom.xml

Comment: First in Eclipse you are using a different compiler furthermore I assume you are using a different version of Java: Something like JDK 6, JDK 7 etc. On maven I can't say either cause there no information about what you have done there (no pom file at all etc.) or information on which JDK you are running using....

Comment: I am using Java 1.7.0_ 45 with eclipse. I want to say that my web project is running fine on tomcat.I  am using maven without eclipse and with Java 1.7.0_ 45.I want to say that in eclipse i can turnoff the validation for generic. Is there any way so that i can turn off the generic validation in maven or pom.xml file which i am using without eclipse.

Comment: You need to take a look into the compiler documentation of the JDK you are using and check if there is such option..cause in Eclipse you are using a different compiler...

Comment: i have done a lot of research for this. Maven provide the option                
1)  disable the compilation process.    2) continue the process even if the error occurred but, in this case class file will not generate for the java file having the errors. So, as per my understanding we should use eclipse compiler and change the compiler setting as per requirement